# Simpson 1/3 double integration with python

Tags: python

I've done double integration with Simson's 1/3 rule. The function is given below-

[image: function]

The answer will be 0.025 but the answer from my code is  0.008869
The formula I have used is -

Simpson 1/3 double integration formula:

[image: Simpson 1/3 double integration formula]

code:

```
a= 4 
b= 4.4
c= 2
d= 2.6
N1= 2
N2=2
h=(b-a)/N1 
k=(d-c)/N2

def f(x,y):
    return (1/(x*y))

for i in range(N1+1):
     r = a+i*h
   for j in range(N2+1):
       t = c + j*k
       first=f(a,c)+f(a,d)
       if i%2==0:
          Xf1 =first+2*f(a,t)
       else:
          Xf1 =first+0
       if i%2!=0:
           Xf2 = Xf1+ 4*f(a,t)
       else:
          Xf2 = Xf1+ 0
    
       last=f(b,c)+f(b,d)
       if i%2==0:
          Xl1 =last +2*f(b,t)
       else:
         Xl1 =last+0
       if i%2!=0:
          Xl2 = Xl1+ 4*f(b,t)
       else:
          Xl2 = Xl1+ 0
    
       if i%2==0:
           even = 2* f(r,t)
       else:
          odd = 4 *f(r,t)
    
    

  print("Xf=",Xf2 )
  print("Xl=",Xl2 )
  print("even=",even )
  print("odd",odd)
  ans = Xl2+Xf2+even+odd
  ans = ((h*k)/9)*ans
  print(ans)
```

Where have I been mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the error is but this works:

```
a= 4.0 
b= 4.4
c= 2.0
d= 2.6
N1= 2
N2=2
h=(b-a)/N1 
k=(d-c)/N2

def f(x,y):
    return (1/(x*y))

mult=[1.0,4.0,1.0]

zum=0
for i in range(N1+1):
    x=i*h+a
    for j in range(N2+1):
        y=j*k+c
        fxy=f(x,y)*mult[i]*mult[j]
        zum+=fxy
        
ans = zum
ans = ((h*k)/9.0)*ans
print(ans)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I have tried the double integration using simpson's 1/3 rule:
link: "https://github.com/Rifamim1999/Neumerical-Integration-/blob/main/Simpson%20double%20integration%201by3.py"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).